Kotlin Shuffle PagingData
I fetch data from my DAO using Remote Mediator and I get the info as PagingData.
I want to shuffle this data every time, so I will get it in different order, is there a way doing so?
should I dod it only in my screen? though I collect the PagingData from the view model like so:
val currentItems = viewModel.itemsList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

and then show them in a lazy column, so I also can't turn that into a list (I think)
